# How to use custom jquery plugins in angular 4

Tags: jquery, angular, plugins, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use a jquery plugin named imgViewer2(https://github.com/waynegm/imgViewer2) in an Angular 4 project.

I installed npm packages and import jquery successfully and use it well. 
However when I try to use **$(element).imgViewer2();** typescript says cannot find the function. I cannot import the plugin correctly.

What is the way to import and work this plugin?

Thank you very much.

[compile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvxpF.png)[when added code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSBFm.png)

**Solved**

Most likely Avaid`s first suggestion,

Added jquery and its plugins refferences to the scripts array in angular-cli.json.

```
...
scripts: [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/imgViewer2/imgViewer2.min.js"
],
...
```

then just add the following line to your .ts file to use jQuery.

`declare var $: JQuery;`

now `$` comes with functions and properties which added by the plugin. I do not know if there is a better way to do this but for know this is the painless one for me. Thanks.

Comment: is imgViewer2.min.js imported correctly ?

Comment: yes it works when i call $("#image1").imgViewer2(); from console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the typings for jquery don't include any reference to `imgViewer2`, you can patch that in your component source by including this bit:

```ts
declare var $: JQuery;

declare global {
  interface JQuery {
    (selector: string): JQuery;
    imgViewer2(): JQuery;
  }
}
```

This will let typescript know that it is ok to call `imgViewer2()` as a method on an object of type `JQuery` (which I assume you already define since you've said you're using jquery in your app)

Add this code in the same file where you want to make the call to `imgViewer2`, in the global level.

**EDIT**

To complete this answer, in order to use jquery properly in the application add it to the `scripts` array inside the file `.angular-cli.json` thus:

```
scripts: [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
]
```

Then use the above declaration in your component, here's a sample skeleton component:

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare var $: JQuery;

declare global {
  interface JQuery {
    (selector: string): JQuery;
    imgViewer2(): JQuery;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    console.log($);
    $('div#myDiv').imgViewer2();
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Alternatively, if you install the jquery typings `npm i --save-dev @types/jquery` then you can use a somewhat different strategy which is more strongly typed:

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import 'jquery';

declare global {
  interface JQuery {
    imgViewer2(): JQuery;
  }
}
```

Note that you now have to `import 'jquery'`, you dont have to `declare var $...`, and also that you don't have to repeat the call signature, as it is already defined for you in the typings library.

Comment: The `declare global` encompassing construct is not strictly necessary, by the way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Avaid . A clear explanation but I did not understand where should I add the code snippet clearly. Where are the jquery typings stored?

Comment: Add it in the same file where you have your `imgViewer2` call, at the global level.

Comment: I edit the question and add two pictures. When I added the code snippet it does not compiled.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot a critical element, JQuery must also have a call signature, I added that to my answer: `(selector: string): JQuery`

Comment: May I ask one more question. With this signiture I can only pass string parameters to jquery ex. $('#id') but cannot use this way $(document) etc. What kind of signiture should I do. Replacing 'string' with 'any' will work?

Comment: Yes I guess this will work... I have a feeling there must be a better way, maybe by installing `@types/jquery` but I haven't exhausted my attempts on this matter... So feel free to update me if you find anything new :)

Comment: installind `@types/jquery` also handles call signiture and declare operations. Just tried. This very easy steps crazy me 2 days :)

Comment: @oktykrk check if my "edit 2" is similar to what you are doing in your code, and if not, let me know so I can improve the answer

Comment: if you install the jquery typings `npm i --save-dev @types/jquery`, you do not need to `import 'jquery';` and `declare var $: JQueryStatic;` anymore it is coming globally.

Comment: Not for me, I am getting this kind of errors: `src/app/app.component.ts(22,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name '$'.`

Comment: **Sorry** `import 'jquery'` still needed. just do not need to declare $ anymore,

Comment: Avaid, how about non-function properties? We tell typescript imgViewer2() is a JQuery function by adding `imgViewer2(): JQuery;` But now I have a property `$.wgm` and it does not compiling because of wgm is not found in $. How can I solve this?

Comment: Just add `wgm` as a data member to the interface.

Comment: Just like `wgm: JQuery` ?

Comment: It's definitely not of type `JQuery`. I would use `any` for lack of better option

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. This method works when using like `$(element).wgm` but I am trying to use `$.wgm`.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. This method works when using like `$(element).wgm` but I am trying to use `$.wgm`.

Comment: Maybe try merging it with the `JQueryStatic` interface which is the type of $

Comment: Actually I am trying to use it like `$.widget("wgm.imgNotes2", $.wgm.imgViewer2,...` Is 'wgm' something special? Am I missing a package or something?

Comment: I don't know what wgm is... I thought you did :-)

Comment: It is coming with `imgViewer2` then :) I will focus on this. If can solve will notify you. Thanks:)

Comment: Avaid the first way you suggested solved my problem. I added script refferences to `scripts: [ .. ]` and just `declare var $: JQuery;` in component .ts file. Recognized that: 
`declare global {
  interface JQuery {
    (selector: string): JQuery;
    imgViewer2(): JQuery;
  }
}` 
is not required. I am posting final solution as an answer. It is most likely your first suggest.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

Added jquery and its plugins refferences to the scripts array in angular-cli.json.

```
...
scripts: [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/imgViewer2/imgViewer2.min.js"
],
...
```

then just add the following line to your .ts file to use jQuery.

```
declare var $: JQuery;
```

now `$` comes with functions and properties which added by the plugin.
I do not know if there is a better way to do this but for know this is the painless one for me. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest editing your question with the final solution instead of adding an answer like this